# Copy-pasting code loses line-breaks (ie)

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pasting code from Stackoverflow to notepad loses line breaks using IE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11428/pasting-code-from-stackoverflow-to-notepad-loses-line-breaks-using-ie)

You could add the "pre" tag programmatically.

Comment: I guess you are talking about this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11428/pasting-code-from-stackoverflow-to-notepad-loses-line-breaks-using-ie

Comment: better yet, if you have a choice, don't use IE! ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Select the block of code and then click the "101010" button or press "Ctrl-K".

Comment: @Jonathan: :) nice