# Got single line after pasting the code!

Tags: bug, source-code

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prettified code copied in Internet Explorer pastes without line breaks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83992/prettified-code-copied-in-internet-explorer-pastes-without-line-breaks)

Sometimes, when I want to test some code snippet, I copy it as it is and I got the entire code in a single line when I paste it on Eclipse (same problem happens when I paste it in Notepad).

i.e:

When I copy this code:

```
public static void heapSort(int[] data)
{
    heapCreate(data);
    for(int end = data.length-1; end >= 1; end--)
    {
        swap(data, 0, end);
        siftDown(data, 0, end-1);
    }
}
```

I got the following single line after pasting it:

```
public static void heapSort(int[] data){    heapCreate(data);    for(int end = data.length-1; end >= 1; end--)    {        swap(data, 0, end);        siftDown(data, 0, end-1);    }}
```

Btw, my os is windows 7.