# Why can't I easily paste code into Visual Studio from the Stack Overflow site?

Tags: bug, internet-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prettified code copied in Internet Explorer pastes without line breaks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83992/prettified-code-copied-in-internet-explorer-pastes-without-line-breaks)

When I copy code from Stack Overflow into Visual Studio 2010, all the line feeds seem to be gone.
I need to copy code into Word and then copy from Word to Visual Studio. Can Stack Overflow reformat these Code boxes to work with Visual Studio?

For example, the code fragment at [C# Encrypt an XML File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086049/c-encrypt-an-xml-file), when it is copied and pasted into Visual Studio, goes in as one big line.

Here is the code from the link I included. It is short and simple. I actually am using this fragment:

> key = new RijndaelManaged();  byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Password1234"); //password here byte[] saltBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Salt"); // salt here (another string) PasswordDeriveBytes p = new PasswordDeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltBytes); // sizes are devided by 8 because [ 1 byte = 8 bits ] key.IV = p.GetBytes(key.BlockSize / 8); key.Key = p.GetBytes(key.KeySize / 8);

This is how code goes into Visual Studio. As you can see, the linebreaks are mangled.

If fixing this is low priority, just say so; but don't insult my intelligence by telling me to use another browser or that copy/paste is foolish.

When used, someone has to go through this code and sort it all out. Sometimes we are looking at a lot of lines. Stack Overflow provides a great place to share/learn. But why should I have to type things like this in order to use the knowledge?

Answer (score 14):

This problem is [caused by IE, not VS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136443/why-doesnt-ie7-copy-precode-blocks-to-the-clipboard-correctly). You might want to consider using a different browser.

Answer (score -3):

Because it is incredibly <strike>stupid foolish</strike> unwise to copypaste code from the internets into your code.

Code you found online should be read, understood, and then reproduced from that understanding.

However, your *immediate* problem is an IE issue, nothing to do with the implementation of these sites.

Comment: So I should read, understand and reproduce linux and all OSS? I think you're being a lot unrealistic here - sometimes copying and pasting is exactly the right way to go.

Comment: @Roddy: So you're all k with copying code you found online and pasting it into your own?

Comment: @Won't ಠ_ಠ Sometimes you need to copy-paste in case you are typing something wrong or can't deduce the exact character being used.  Especially if characters are similar (i.e. . versus ,)

Comment: I copy code from SO questions into LinqPad all the time.

Comment: This might be true, but it's a horrible answer, as it more or less implies that the site does this on purpose to discourage. Especially from a diamond.

Comment: @Rosinante you make too many assumptions.  Also, if having a diamond means that I can no longer have an opinion then I resign.

Comment: Oh, please. You can have all the opinions you like. I'll tell you what, I'll make a trivial edit to your answer to address my complaint, and remove my downvote.