# What's happened with copy and paste?

Tags: support, paste

I want to copy and paste a small code snippet from OneNote into an answer.  I have done this dozens of times, but today when I attempt it, the window thinks I want to paste in an image or a link.  I just want a simple copy and paste of text.  How do I convince it that's all I want?

In response to comments: I am working on a Windows 10 machine using Firefox.  Also, several people have pointed to another similar question.  However, the answer there did not help me with my issue.

Comment: I didn't notice anything.

Comment: Are you on an Apple device?

Comment: similar: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320162/cant-paste-data-to-question-get-prompted-for-image

Comment: Some comments disappeared on me here.  Anyway, someone asked me to show what I am trying to paste.  Well, cant' do it -- because I have the same problem here that I had originally!

Comment: I deleted my comment in response to your edit, as you addressed my concern. Could you copy what it is you're trying to copy paste, and instead of using *Ctrl+V* to paste, could you right-click and try using "Paste as Plain Text" and see what happens?

Comment: Where does that text come from, from which program? And you can make a screenshot (that is an image after all) and include that in your question.

Comment: rene  It's from MS OneNote.  It's just a code snippet.  Very short.

Comment: Hm. I believe this has been reported before, but it is very old: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333886/622284

Comment: @Spevacus  Thanks for the suggestion, but "Paste as Plain Text" does not show as an option.  "Paste" is all I get.

Comment: @Spevacus  Thanks again, but the solution in the old question doesn't work for me.  When I try it, nothing happens at all.

Comment: I'm pretty sure OneNote has a complex Clipboard type and that will confuse the paste function here. Open notepad first, paste from OneNote into notepad, then ctrl+a, ctrl+c in Notepad, switch to your SE post, ctrl+v.

Comment: @rene That did it!  Notepad works.  Thanks!

Comment: @SonictheMaskedWerehog  No.  Didn't get anything with that at all.  rene's Notepad idea worked.  Thanks.

Comment: This is [the *opposite* question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147478/282094) which suggests [rene's advice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354486/whats-happened-with-copy-and-paste#comment1184553_354486) as an answer.

Comment: @bob.sacamento now the duplicate applies fully ;)